# MySQL ／ 条件一致していたら、指定カラムのDB値そのものを、別テーブルのカラム値で、上書き更新したい

Tags: mysql

**前提**
**A(人)テーブル … b_idカラム、都道府県カラム**
**B(マスター)テーブル … idカラム、都道府県カラム**

・AとBの関係は多対1
・b_idカラムの中身は空
・両テーブルの都道府県カラムには、神奈川県などの文字列が格納されています

・b_idカラム、idカラム … int
・都道府県カラム … varchar

---

**やりたいこと**
・ABテーブルの都道府県カラム内容(の文字列)が一致していたら、Aテーブルのb_idカラムを、Bテーブルのidカラムの値で上書き更新したい

・どうすれば良いでしょうか？

ALTER TABLE B.b_id？？？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html
によると、

```
UPDATE A,B SET A.b_id = B.id where A.pref = B.pref;
```

のようですね、MySQLでは。
老婆心ながら、この更新はAテーブルのほぼ全件に更新がかかり、A,Bテーブルがその間ロックされるでしょうから運用中にやれば運用に支障が出るでしょう。

Comment: 日本語のドキュメントがあったので貼っておきます。http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/ja/update.html

Comment: 期待通り動作しましたー。ちなみに、ロックされる、とは、UPDATEが常に優先される、ことになるのでしょうか？　UPDATE処理自体については問題ないが、それを優先させてしまうので、他の処理に影響が出る可能性があるってことでしょうか？

Comment: RDBというのは、アトミックに変更をするものと決まっていて、UPDATEの変更対象がたくさんあっても、少しづつ書き換えたりはしません。他からはアクセスされないようにして変更を始め、終わったら開放します。数行なら気が付かないうちに終わりますが、例えば全レコードの更新に10分かかると、10分間は他のクエリはUPDATEが処理中のデータにアクセスできなくなるという意味です。そうしないと、他のクエリの結果に矛盾ができてしまうことがあるためそうなっています。

Answer (score 1):

トランザクションテーブル（Aテーブル）からマスタテーブル（Bテーブル）を作りたいとの事。
Update文の文法は、先の方の回答の通りかと思いますが、Aテーブルの id カラムと都道府県カラムの組み合わせは一意の前提なんでしょうか？
人テーブルとかかれているので、データを追加していくテーブル（トランザクション）に見えますが、その組み合わせが一意でないと、Aテーブルのデータによって、マスタが更新されることになりますが、それはそれでいいのですか？
また、バッチ的に実行するにしても、結果が安定しないと思われます。

Comment: 予定としては、手動でバッチ的に実行しようと考えています。
Aテーブルの id カラムと都道府県カラムの組み合わせについては、Aテーブルの id カラムにAUTO_INCREMENT を設定しているのですが、それだけでは結果が安定しないのでしょうか？

Comment: すいません。勘違いがありました。上記の私のコメントは気にしないでください。
出来るなら、Aテーブルにデータを入れるタイミングで、Bテーブルを読む作りの方がいいと思います。
また、バッチであれば、Update文を一発流せばOKだと思います。
件数増に対応するなら、AテーブルのIDカラムがNULL or ブランクのデータにだけUpdateがかかるようにwhere句を追加すれば良いでしょう。